# How to send GET/POST request on a flask based local website?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, rest, flask

I have a website which takes a .txt file as input through an upload button. The backend model processes this text file and output a new .txt file. My website is working perfectly with the UI. But I was trying to send GET/POST request to my file using the curl command:

```
curl -F 'file=@CNN.txt' http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

The output was that my whole html file got printed (as a cat command does) in the terminal.
I want to know how can I get the processed file using the curl command itself? I think to get the file, I need to return some kind of JSON object too. I am completely new to this stuff. Please bare with me.. My appy.py file is:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        if('file' not in request.files):
            return 'NO FILE'
        file = request.files['file']
        if(file.filename == ''):
            print('NO FILES')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if(file and allowed_file(file.filename)):
            uploadedFile = file.filename
            file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename))
            if(uploadedFile != ''):
                neural_code_sum.starter(uploadedFile)
            return render_template('index.html', message='success')
    return render_template('index.html', message='NOT UPLOADED (ONLY .TXT FILES ALLOWED)')


@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    global uploadedFile
    doc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/output.txt'
    return send_file(doc,as_attachment=True,cache_timeout=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add GET above:

```
@app.route('/download', methods = ['GET'])
def download_file():
    global uploadedFile
    doc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/output.txt'
    return send_file(doc,as_attachment=True,cache_timeout=0)
```

The first send the file: `curl -F 'file=@CNN.txt' http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Then download it: `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/download -o output.txt`

That's it! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/download',methods=['**GET'**])
def download_file():
global uploadedFile
doc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/output.txt'
return send_file(doc,as_attachment=True,cache_timeout=0)
```

Add the method by which you want to send the request in the methods field.